# generics in Groovy

Tags: java, generics, groovy

The following Groovy code prints "it works"

```
def printIt(Class<? extends Exception> clazz) {
  println "it works"
}

printIt(String.class)
```

even though the parameter doesn't satisfy the constraint `Class<? extends Exception>`

My understanding is that this is because:

1. Type erasure in Java generics means there's no run-time generic type checking
2. There is no compile-time type checking in Groovy

These two points means there's effectively no checking of bounded generic types in Groovy. Is there any way I can check (at runtime) that the `Class` object passed to `printIt` satisfies the constraint `? extends Exception`

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 4):

Check out this [link](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Generics).

> [...]In some ways this is at odds with the
> emphasis of dynamic languages where in
> general, the type of objects can not
> be determined until runtime. But
> Groovy aims to accomodate Java's
> static typing when possible, hence
> Groovy 1.5 now also understands
> Generics. Having said that, Groovy's
> generics support doesn't aim to be a
> complete clone of Java's generics.
> Instead, Groovy aims to allow generics
> at the source code level (to aid cut
> and pasting from Java) and also where
> it makes sense to allow good
> integration between Groovy and Java
> tools and APIs that use generics.[...]

In conclusion, I don't think it's possible to obtain that information at runtime.

Comment: I wonder what exactly is meant by: 'Groovy currently does a little further and throws away generics information "at the source level"'

Comment: I think this means that generic information is simply ignored in groovy. In Java, generics information is removed but the appropriate casts and static type checking is made.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know it's supposed to be an Exception, this works in Java (or Groovy):

```
// true if the class is a subclass of Exception
Exception.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
```

That in no way uses the generic information, but that wouldn't be available in Java either.