# List<T> return anomaly for method accepting varargs List<? extends T>

Tags: java, generics, groovy, variadic-functions

In the following code, I was expecting the return type to be of type `List<A>` but it turns out to be of type `List<Ax>` (the type of the first varargs paramater). If someone can make sense of why this is the case please explain it to me. Notice also that a returned list of a particular type actually holds elements of sibling types.

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

@CompileStatic
class Main {
    static main(args) {
      List<Ax> axl = [new Ax()]
      List<Ay> ayl = [new Ay()]
      List<Az> azl = [new Az()]

      // List<A> list1 = Util.join(axl, ayl, azl)
      // Error: Incompatible generic argument types. Cannot assign java.util.List <Ax>
      //        to: java.util.List <A>

      List<A> list2 = Util.join(axl, ayl, azl) as List<A>  // coercion works
      list2.each { A a -> println a.getClass() } // 3 different types     

      List<Ax> list3 = Util.join(axl, ayl, azl) // List<Ax> holds Ay and Az!!! Type system flawed
      // list3.each { Ax a -> println a.getClass() } // some weird error
      list3.each { A a -> println a.getClass() } // 3 different types
    }
}

@CompileStatic class A {}
@CompileStatic class Ax extends A {}
@CompileStatic class Ay extends A {}
@CompileStatic class Az extends A {}

@CompileStatic
class Util {
    static <T> List<T> join(List<? extends T>... lists) {
        List<T> joined = [] 
        lists.each { List<? extends T> list ->
          list.each { T elm -> joined.add(elm) }
        }
        return joined
    }
}
```

*Note: Groovy Version: 2.4.7*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2008337/4969140 I believe this could be helpful.

Comment: The referenced post is not under static compilation.

Comment: This is looks like a compiler bug. I'd suggest you to file a bug to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY